# how to tell R to detect structure at the beginning of the word across rows

Tags: r, string, if-statement, dplyr

Is there a way to combine the `for loop`, `grep` and `case_when` functions in the **dplyr** package to automate some tasks? As an example, I have a data frame in which the first column contains a gene symbol. Then, I want to create a 2nd column called **annotation** based on the gene symbol information. For example, when **gene_symbol** starts with a character "COL," I want to annotate it as "Collagens" in the 2nd column. If it begins with "FGF," then it is a glycoprotein in the 2n column.

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data.frame(gene_symbole = as.character(c("CD226","CD276","CD320","CD58","FGF","FGGR", "FGF1","FGFR", "COL12","COLA12","COLB13","BCFGF","BCCOL")))
```

Thank you!!
Best
adr

Comment: It sounds like you want to do a join/merge. Where are these annotations coming from? Do you have a second data.frame that contains these annotations? We would need more complete information to make a specific recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

No need for a `for` loop:

```
data %>% 
  mutate(
    annotation=case_when(
      stringr::str_sub(gene_symbole, 1, 3) == "COL" ~ "Collagen",
      stringr::str_sub(gene_symbole, 1, 3) == "FGF" ~ "Glycoprotein",
      TRUE ~ NA_character_
    )
  )
# A tibble: 13 × 2
   gene_symbole annotation  
   <chr>        <chr>       
 1 CD226        NA          
 2 CD276        NA          
 3 CD320        NA          
 4 CD58         NA          
 5 FGF          Glycoprotein
 6 FGGR         NA          
 7 FGF1         Glycoprotein
 8 FGFR         Glycoprotein
 9 COL12        Collagen    
10 COLA12       Collagen    
11 COLB13       Collagen    
12 BCFGF        NA          
13 BCCOL        NA
```

Comment: if you don't have stringr, maybe substr(gene_symbole,1,3) could replace stringr::str_sub(gene_symbole,1,3).  Also, the "1" in either case represents the starting character position and the 3 represents the ending position.  So, if you string is of a different length, you may need to adjust this.

Comment: @Limey  thank you. But why you used the number 1 and 3 in the str_sub function . just to know!

Comment: They indicate that I'm searching between the first and third character positions of `gene_symbole`.  Details are in the online doc.